# Replace let bound variables with symbol value during byte-compile

Tags: emacs, bytecode

How can I replace a let-bound variable with its value in emacs when byte-compiling?  For example, say I have some variable `my-auto`, can I replace its symbol-name with its value in the function?

```
(defvar my-auto "somefile.el")

(defun test ()
  (let ((generated-autoload-file my-auto))
    (prin1 generated-autoload-file)))
```

After byte-compile I get (some symbols won't show, but you get the idea)

```
(defalias 'test #[nil "\302 !)\207" [my-auto generated-autoload-file prin1] 2])
```

But, can I instead get

```
(defalias 'test #[nil "\301\302!)\207" [generated-autoload-file "somefile.el" prin1] 2])
```

where `my-auto` has been replaced with "somefile.el"?  I think I could write some sort of macro, but I'm not sure how and am trying to refactor a bunch of functions.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821). What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you defining a global, dynamic variable, if you want only its value in your function `test`?  Please consider posing your real question: what you are really trying to do.

Anyway, this does what you apparently (think you) want:

```
;;; foo.el --- tools -*- lexical-binding:t -*-

(eval-and-compile
  (let ((var  "somefile.el"))

    (defvar my-auto var)

    (defun test ()
      (let ((generated-autoload-file var))
        (prin1 generated-autoload-file)))))
```

Be sure to put that in a *file*, with the first line having the `lexical-binding` declaration.  Byte-compile the file.  Load the byte-compiled file.  Then check `(symbol-function 'test)`.  You will see something like this:

```
#[0 "\300\301!\207"
    ["somefile.el" prin1]
    3 "\n\n(fn)"]
```

---

---

**Added by the OP, jenesaisquoi.  This is apparently what s?he ended up doing:**

Another alternative would be to create a macro that gets expanded when byte-compiled, like

```
(defmacro expand-thing (place)
  (or (and (symbolp place) (symbol-value place))
      ;; or do other checks
      (eval place)))
```

Then, after byte-compiling (require the macro first!)

```
(defun test ()
  (let ((generated-autoload-file (expand-thing my-auto)))
    (prin1 generated-autoload-file)))
```

the result should be as expected.